# Grafana not picking up my metrics from graphite

Tags: graphite

I installed graphite and grafana which I can both access through web. I was sending some test metrics to the machine using a SSC Serv Utility, which is basically a windows tool where you enter you graphite URL / IP and it starts sending common metrics from performance monitor. CPU / Memory etc.

In my graphite I see all the incoming metrics already but grafana stays empty.

I assume my database settings are not correct, here are my grafana settings:

```
// Graphite & Elasticsearch example setup

datasources: {
  graphite: {
    type: 'graphite',
    url: "localhost:80",
  },
  elasticsearch: {
    type: 'elasticsearch',
    url: "http://my.elastic.server.com:9200",
    index: 'grafana-dash',
    grafanaDB: true,
  }
},
```

localhost:80 is the url for my graphite website and I have grafana running on port 81.

What could I be missing? Thx in advance, every help is upvoted.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. It got resolved for me when I replaced "url" under graphite to the server DNS instead of localhost as below. Also, make sure you can access this URL from your web browser. If not, verify the port.

```js
graphite: {
    type: 'graphite',
    url: "http://my.graphite.server:80",
  },
```